# Custom Content Type always results in ArgumentException

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, content-type, page-layout, publishing-page

I created a custom content type and provisioned it as a solution for SharePoint 2013 (PU March). When I create a new page in a list, bam yellow page of death.

To rule out an error I created a custom content type with the UI - inherits from article page with **no additional fields**. Then I added it to a document library. After assigning a name to the new page and submitting the form => yellow page of death with the following stack:

`System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateParentFoldersForFile(SPList list, String url, Boolean createAsListItem)

 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreatePagePage.NewPageItemSave(String pageName, PageLayout pageLayout, String folderUrl, Boolean redirect)

 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreatePagePage.CreateStandardPage(String pageName)

 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreatePagePage.ButtonCreatePage_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)

 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)`

Any clues?

**Update1**: When the parent of the content type is an article page it crashes. When the parent is a Basic Page it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function SPUtility.CreateParentFoldersForFile verfifies that the new item based on a publishing content type is stored in the Pages library. If not you get the error above.

Key takeaway: Publishing Content types only in the Publishing Library, aka. Pages.

Answer (score 1):

First I think you mean by adding the content type to a page library.  The ArgumentException could occur due to a invalid list.  Here's what I would try:

- Try it in a new subsite page library.
- Add a custom content type to a custom page layout and create a page in a new subsite page library to see if you have the same problem
- The error shows Publishing is involved.  Try turn off publishing feature in a subsite and see if you are still having problem.