# Content Type creates System.ArgumentException in Document Library

Tags: 2013, document-library, content-type, page-layout

I created a custom content type and a page layout for it. `Publishing Feature` is activated on my site collection. Now, I can flawlessly create some pages out of this content type in the `Pages Library`.

Now, I want to create a document library with my custom content type as default type, but when I want to create a page, I get :

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateParentFoldersForFile(SPList list, String url, Boolean createAsListItem)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreatePagePage.NewPageItemSave(String pageName, PageLayout pageLayout, String folderUrl, Boolean redirect)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreatePagePage.CreateStandardPage(String pageName)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreatePagePage.ButtonCreatePage_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint...
```

Comment: hate this error. had one like that about expected range, turned out to be a column added programatically with AddFieldAsXml that then had duplicate fields. possibly not your case, but thought I would mention. maybe check ULS for more details

Comment: Is it even possible to store application pages in a library other than the Pages library?

Comment: This error message is out of ULS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this Question: [Custom Content Type always results in ArgumentException](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75879/custom-content-type-always-results-in-argumentexception)

> The function SPUtility.CreateParentFoldersForFile verfifies that the new item based on a publishing content type is stored in the Pages library. If not you get the error above.
>
> Key takeaway: Publishing Content types only in the Publishing Library, aka. Pages.